# codeigniter, moving to live site, An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file: helpers/colordatedeadline_helper.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I was trying to go live on an application I build in codeigniter, but it kept telling me "Unable to load the requested file: helpers/writetolog_helper.php".

I originally had them autoloaded in the config file.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'cookie', 'ColorDateDeadline', 'CalculateMinTohours', 'WriteToLog');
```

after that didn't work I tried to autoload them in the controller __construct.

```
 class Customers extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('customer');
        $this->load->helper('WriteToLog');
    }
```

The WriteToLog function contains the following code:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( !function_exists('WriteToLog'))
{
    function WriteToLog($message , $error=0 ) {
        $clean_message = trim($message);

        if ($error == 1) {
            $real_message   =   "<span style='color: red;'>" . $clean_message . "</span>\r\n";
        } else {
            $real_message   =   "<span style='color: green;'>" . $clean_message . "</span>\r\n";
        }

        $file_handle = fopen(FCPATH . 'logs/logs.txt', 'a+');
        fwrite($file_handle, $real_message);
        fclose($file_handle);
    }
}
```

and the file structure is as follows:

```
-- helpers
     -- CalculateMinTohours_helper.php
     -- WriteToLog_helper.php
```

I got all the methods of implementing it from the 3.0.5 documentation but still it's popping up errors, did I mispells/capitalize something? Also the application works fine on a windows server(XAMPP) but my BLuehost account it started to throw errors on me.

EDIT: when i remove the autoload i can see my login page, so it isn't a routing problem.

Thanks for any input,
rodney

Comment: writetolog_helper.php or colordatedeadline_helper.php ? have you uploaded the helper file?

Comment: Yes both files are within my library folder, all with camel casing.

Comment: helper files belong in the helpers directory...not the library directory.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but as i stated above they are in the helper directory

Comment: Try just having the first letter upper case of filename

Comment: Thanks for the information nullReference. Appearantly it needs to be all lower case. however your answer helped me in the right direction. cheers

Answer (score 0):

helper files need to be all lowercase letters. so in my case i renamed the helper to: writetolog.php